# Do Americans pronounce "transient" as \ˈtran(t)-sh(ē-)ənt\?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, yod-coalescence

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transient) pronounces "transient" as \ˈtran(t)-sh(ē-)ənt\.

However, most [Americans](https://youglish.com/search/transient/us) pronounce it as \ˈtran-zē-ənt\.

Comment: Merriam-Webster gives both pronunciations. Americans pronounce it [both ways](https://forvo.com/word/transient_ischemic_attack/#en). What exactly is your question?

Comment: @PeterShor I watched through several [videos](https://youglish.com/search/transient/us), and found no one read it as \ˈtran(t)-sh(ē-)ənt\, so that I was confused and wondering if it is a widely acceptable pronunciation.

Comment: I sure don't pronounce it that way.

Comment: I put a forvo.com link with both pronunciations in my comment above. But I believe that \ˈtran-zē-ənt\ is quite a bit more frequent.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, I see. However, Merriam-Webster offers the audio only for the \ˈtran(t)-sh(ē-)ənt\ that is less frequently used. It is also the case in Oxford dictionary.

Comment: @Robusto was wondering if you heard \ˈtran(t)-sh(ē-)ənt\ alone, could you figure it out?

Comment: It took me a while to even figure out what that other pronunciation was supposed to be.  I’ve never heard anyone say it that way in real life.

Comment: I am quite sure I have heard both pronunciations in real life.

Comment: @Jim is this an example where the dictionary pronunciation violates the convention?

Comment: Certainly seems to from my perspective, but maybe there’s a whole class of people I don’t know about!?!

Comment: It does look like \ˈtran-zē-ənt\ is by far the preferred pronunciation. Possibly it was pronounced differently in the past, and dictionaries haven't kept up with the pronunciation change. Some evidence for this is that [Walker's pronouncing dictionary](https://archive.org/stream/walkerspronounc00unkngoog#page/n394/mode/2up) from 1828 gives \ˈtran-shē-ənt\

Comment: @GuoyangQin: Of course I could figure it out, especially if that word made sense in context.

Comment: I pronounce it the way it's spelled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merriam-Webster seems a bit of an outlier with its intrusive *t*, though [Cambridge UK](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/transient) adds a *d* in the recorded audio of its suggested American pronunciation.  It sounds like *tangent* only with an intial *tr*. The IPA for that pronunciation is given as

> ˈtræn.zi.ʃənt

which, I trust, is a typographical error. Or a really drunk guy trying for *transigent*.

On their [American page](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/transient#dataset-cacd), there are three choices, one with the added dental consonant:

> ˈtræn·ʃənt, -dʒənt, -zi·ənt

So we have two authorities who add a *d* or *t*.

The American pronunciation depends on whether one gives the word three syllables or, in more rapid speech, just two, in which case the *i* disappears, transforming the *s* into a palato-alveolar fricative, either voiced or unvoiced.

The American three-syllable pronunciation voices the *s* just as the [British](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/transient_1):

> ˈtræn zi ənt

There are a number of examples at [FreeDictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/transient), which aggregates several online dictionaries.
When reduced to two syllables, the *s* palatalizes to either ʃ or ʒ by a process called [*yod-coalescence*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Yod-coalescence) a fairly common feature in English: *vision, measure, education*, etc. This yields:

> ˈtræn ʃənt
>   ˈtræn ʒənt

Now the pronunciations with the added dental stop both sound odd to me, but I assume they’re used somewhere in the US or Canada. Otherwise these dictionaries wouldn’t bother to list them.

Comment: [Kenyon and Knott, on page 436](https://archive.org/stream/pronouncingdicti00unse#page/436/mode/2up/search/transient), say that _transient_ is pronounced **trænʃənt**. I think that may have been the case when the dictionary was first compiled, after WWII, but it's not that common any more. I've been around longer than that dictionary, and I say it with a /z/ (or occasionally an /s/) that's somewhat palatalized, but rarely moves far enough back to be called a shibilant.

Comment: @JohnLawler: That echoes my own pronunciation: I'd give the noun 3 syllables, but the adjective gets palatalized to zh or sh.

Comment: In English, an epenthetic /t/ pretty much appears automatically when you have /ns/ in the same syllable, as in *prince* and *transportation.* (Ditto /nʃ/.)  And words like *cancel* often have this /t/. So if you pronounce *transient* with an /s/, the extra /t/ is pretty much expected. Of course, most people seem to pronounce it with a /z/.